# Change the value of pointed to by a void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I'm not sure how I can store and modify an int using the following stucts in C. I don't think the values that I insert into a student struct are being stored. The student grade must stay `void*` and I need to be able to access/modify the grade at anytime until exiting.

```
typedef struct student{
    void *grade;
} student;

typedef struct school{
    student **students;
    size_t school_size;
}school;

student *student_create(int x){
    student *new_student = malloc(sizeof(student));
    new_student->grade = malloc(sizeof(int));
    new_student->grade = &x;
    return new_student;
}

school *school_create(size_t school_szie) {
    school *s = (school*)malloc(sizeof(school));
    s->students = (student**)malloc(sizeof(student*) * school_szie);

    for (int i = 0; i < school_szie; ++i) {
        s->students[i] = NULL;
    }
    return s;
}

void school_insert(school *s, int count, int index){
    if(s->students[index] == NULL){
        student *new_s = student_create(count);
        s->students[index] = new_s;
    }
}

void student_inc(school *s, int index){
    *(int *)s->students[index]->grade = *(int *)s->students[index]->grade + 1;
}

int main(){

    int a = 10;
    void *ptr = &a;

    printf("%d\n", *(int *)ptr);
    *(int *)ptr = *(int*)ptr + 1;
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)ptr);

    school *s1 = school_create(5);
    
    school_insert(s1, 2, 1); // school name, grade, index
    school_insert(s1, 4, 0);
    school_insert(s1, 7, 3);
    
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)s1->students[1]->grade);
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)s1->students[0]->grade);
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)s1->students[3]->grade);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following output,although the intended output of the last three lines should be 2, 4, 7.

```
10
11
7
7
7
```

Comment: You have a memory leak in `student_create()` and set grade to the address of a local variable that becomes invalid when the function returns...

Comment: In `school_create` you have the assignment `new_student->grade = &x` which will make `new_student->grade` point to the ***local*** variable `x`. The life-time of `x` will end when the function ends, making the pointer invalid. Any dereference of this pointer afterward will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Think about what these two lines do: `new_student->grade = malloc(sizeof(int)); new_student->grade = &x;` The first assigns the pointer to space to store an int. The second overwrites that pointer with the address of a local variable that will be invalid as soon as the function ends. It also create a memory leak. Perhaps you want to copy the value of `x` into the space allocated for it by the first line?

Comment: I'm guessing what you really want is something like `*(int *)new_student->grade = x`?

Comment: Also in `school _insert` you forgot `s->school_size = school_szie;`.

Comment: Having `void *grade;` in `struct student` looks like very, very poor (if not worse) design to me.  Is it part of some assignment? Tell us more. It should be `int grade;`. Also `struct student` should contain at least a name or some student identifier.

Comment: By the way, there has been [some discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and the consensus seems to be *not* to cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues. Look at the commented lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
  void* grade;
} student;

typedef struct school {
  student** students;
  size_t school_size;
}school;

student* student_create(int x) {
  student* new_student = malloc(sizeof(student));
  new_student->grade = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *(int*)(new_student->grade) = x;            // changed
  return new_student;
}

school* school_create(size_t school_szie) {
  school* s = (school*)malloc(sizeof(school));
  s->students = (student**)malloc(sizeof(student*) * school_szie);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < school_szie; ++i) {
    s->students[i] = NULL;
  }

  s->school_size = school_szie;               // you forgot this
  return s;
}

void school_insert(school* s, int count, int index) {
  if (s->students[index] == NULL) {
    student* new_s = student_create(count);
    s->students[index] = new_s;
  }
}

void student_inc(school* s, int index) {
  *(int*)s->students[index]->grade = *(int*)s->students[index]->grade + 1;
}

int main() {

  int a = 10;
  void* ptr = &a;

  printf("%d\n", *(int*)ptr);
  *(int*)ptr = *(int*)ptr + 1;
  printf("%d\n", *(int*)ptr);

  school* s1 = school_create(5);

  school_insert(s1, 2, 1); // school name, grade, index
  school_insert(s1, 4, 0);
  school_insert(s1, 7, 3);

  printf("%d\n", *(int*)(s1->students[1]->grade));   // changed
  printf("%d\n", *(int*)(s1->students[0]->grade));   // changed
  printf("%d\n", *(int*)(s1->students[3]->grade));   // changed

  return 0;
}
```

---

This doesn't make sens for two reasons:

```
new_student->grade = malloc(sizeof(int));
new_student->grade = &x;
```

1. `new_student->grade = &x` overwrites `new_student->grade` that has been allocated on the previous line
2. `new_student->grade = &x` puts the *pointer* to the local variable `x` into
   `new_student->grade`, but this local variable will cease to exist once the `student_create` function is over.

You want: `*(int*)(new_student->grade) = x;`. You've done it right with your tests using `a` and `ptr` at the beginning of `main`.

---

You forgot to assign the school size in `school_create`

```
 s->school_size = school_szie;               // you forgot this
```

---

This is wrong:

```
printf("%d\n", s1->students[1]->grade);
```

`s1->students[1]->grade` is the *pointer*  to the grade, but you want the grade itself. Here you pretend `s1->students[1]->grade` is actually an `int`, and `printf` prints this as if it was an `int`. This is undefined bahaviour, the value printed can be any garbage value.

Therefore you need `*(int *)s1->students[1]->grade`. `(int *)` casts the pointer to `void` to a pointer to `int`, and the `*` dereferences the pointer to `int`.

---

Finally you should use `size_t` isntead of `int` in this for loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < school_szie; ++i)
```

`school_szie` being a `size_t`.

This last problem however has no impact on the program output here.

---

That being said, be aware that having `void *grade` in `struct student` looks like very, very poor (if not worse) design to me. It should be `int grade`. You want to store a grade.

Also `struct student` should probably contain at least a student name or some student identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your program with `gcc -g main.c -o main` and ran it with `valgrind ./main` to find memory issues quickly. Try it!

Valgrind complains about conditional jumps depending on uninitialized values for the last 3 printf statements. That means the 3 grades aren't initialized.

Though it took some digging to find the problem. It's in:

```
student *student_create(int x){
    student *new_student = malloc(sizeof(student));
    new_student->grade = malloc(sizeof(int));
    new_student->grade = &x;
    return new_student;
}
```

The `new_student->grade = &x;` line is setting `grade` to be a pointer to the argument `x`, which will be completely invalid when the function returns! You really want `*(int*)new_student->grade = x`, which writes `x` to the newly-allocated memory location.

Answer (score 0):

Well this doesn't make much sense:

```
new_student->grade = malloc(sizeof(int));
new_student->grade = &x;
```

Memory is allocated and assigned to `new_student->grade`, then that is promptly overwritten by a pointer to a parameter. So you have now a memory leak (you can never again free the allocated memory) and undefined behaviour as that pointer to a local variable is no longer valid after the function returns.

What you want to do is allocate an integer, assign it a value, and then assign the pointer to it to `new_student->grade`.

```
int *grade = malloc(sizeof *grade);
if (!grade) {
   // handle the error properly (not shown here)
   return NULL;
}
*grade = x;
new_student->grade = grade;
```